# VS2010 compiler and cuda error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous “hypot”

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvcc

When I try to build my project on a 64 bit Windows 7 using VS 2010 in Debug 64 bit configuration I get this error along with two other errors.

error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "hypot" in math.h line 161
error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "hypotf" in math.h line 161
error: function "abs(long long)" has already been defined in math_functions.h line 534

I do not get these errors in the 32 bit build. Also, the 64 bit build worked in VS2008. Is there a proper work around to this problem or should I just wait till nvcc supports VS 2010 compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was changed in VS2010:

```
/* hypot and hypotf are now part of the C99 Standard */
static __inline double __CRTDECL hypot(_In_ double _X, _In_ double _Y)
{
    return _hypot(_X, _Y);
}
```

Not sure about the abs() error, the line number looks wrong.  The math_functions.h header is no longer compatible with VS2010, something is going to have to give.  Review the need to still have to #include math.h, it ought to be functionally replaced by Cuda.  Hacking the header would be another way to get past the problem until they fix it:

```
#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || _MSC_VER < 0x1400
    // hypotf definition here...
#endif
```

Comment: VS10 here also, similar C2373 clash with `MonitorFromWindow` in the 7.1 SDK. Could you provide more details on the header hack please?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with this Q+A, click the Ask Question button.

Comment: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720852/windows7-1-sdk-c2373-monitorfromwindow-redefinition).