# Windows7.1 SDK: C2373: "MonitorFromWindow" Redefinition

Tags: c++, winapi, monitor

The error "linkage specification is incompatible with previous "MonitorFromWindow"" in 32 bit build VS10 MCBS is given for the following decl:

```
 int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HMONITOR MonitorFromWindow(_In_ HWND  hwnd, _In_ DWORD dwFlags);

    return DialogBoxW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(lpTemplate), nullptr, DlgProc);
}
```

Assumed the solution would be similar to the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685773/vs2010-compiler-and-cuda-error-linkage-specification-is-incompatible-with-previ), but here it might be some problem with the SDK although some kind of header hack is preferred.

Comment: You've missed the introductory text that explains what you are doing, what you are compiling, what your code is, and how to reproduce the error.

Comment: @David: Is the edit sufficient? The obvious problem is that we don't have a hwnd yet, but I am sure that problem is unrelated to the error.

Comment: You *declared* MonitorFromWindow, what was the point of that??  Sure, it is not compatible with the real declaration, which is __declspec(dllimport) and uses the __stdcall calling convention.  Did you mean to call it?

Comment: In unchartered territory here,It has been recommended to check for multiple displays [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669717/dialogex-with-controls-resizing/35677109#35677109) - and which display uses the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that your declaration of `MonitorFromWindow` conflicts with the prior declaration. The prior declaration in `Winuser.h` declared the function with `extern "C"` linkage, is `__declspec(dllimport)` and has the `__stdcall` calling convention.

You should remove your erroneous declaration and use that from the header file.

Comment: Interesting: Winuser.h tells me: `WINUSERAPI HMONITOR  WINAPI MonitorFromWindow( __in HWND hwnd,  __in DWORD dwFlags);` Does that conform to your assertion?

Comment: Ah: the double underscore is stdcall: got it.

Comment: What is hard to understand is you would try to declare this function at all rather than use the header file?

Comment: We get the "type name is not allowed" for HWND when calling the function.

Comment: Well, I cannot see your code that calls the function, so I cannot comment on that. All I've done is answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Thanks David, to call the function all that is tried is to remove HMONITOR in the above code, and compiled it with and without the "__In__". is that for another question, because a solution here does not appear obvious.

Comment: Remove that declaration entirely, and call the function like this: `HMONITOR hMon = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);`. It looks like you have some basic misunderstandings on how functions are declared, and how they are called. I suggest that you revisit your C++ text book.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/dd145064(v=vs.85).aspx) wants updating perhaps?

Comment: No, the MSDN page is accurate. What do you feel is wrong with it?

Comment: Oops sorry to have wasted your time. I guess the MSDN page could have an example or community comment section. Also an included link to a list of parameters like the suggested MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST.

Comment: It does describe the available flags. There are listed right there. There are some basic pre-requisites for reading documentation like this. I don't think it would help if every such documentation topic had to start from the ground floor. Understanding how to call a function, and what a window handle is are pre-requisites here.

Comment: I understand. I've been calling functions (correctly and incorrectly) for years- probably longer than you? :), but never got that  linkage error of which one of the few documented cases are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685773/vs2010-compiler-and-cuda-error-linkage-specification-is-incompatible-with-previ).

Comment: @LaurieStearn: You still don't seem to quite understand. Your code is buggy. You are **not** calling a function. You are **declaring** a function (and doing it wrong, while at it, hence the error message). There is no issue with library files or the MSDN documentation. You simply don't seem to understand **very basic** concepts of C programming, case in point being: How to call a function. Getting this wrong after years of calling functions leaves me somewhat astonished.

Comment: IInspectable: Always pasted func decls in before using them. That's my way. And I know the errors that come up. But as the linkage error had *very* poor documentation, and as I was encouraged by Hans to open a new thread, (see above post) we get shot down in flames. Grrrr.

Comment: You should stop pasting function declarations. Let them be declared in header files which you include.